# Java - Reading/Scanning a text file for string length and using it in the program

Tags: java, string, file, search

I am trying to make a simple game of hangman in Java. I do have a text file named dictionary.txt containing 120K words from the English dictionary. The problem arises when I am going to prompt the user for a word length and displaying number of words with that particular length.

After spending a fair amount of time here and googling I have gotten this far but now I am stuck:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Hangman 

{


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // declaring variables
    int wordLength;
    int guessNumber;


    // initiate the scanner
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

    // read the dictionary file 

    File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;



    // prompt the user for word length

    System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman. Let's play! ");
    System.out.println("Please enter the desired word length: ");
    wordLength = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(wordLength < 0 || wordLength > 26)
    {
        System.out.println("This is not a valid word length. ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired word length: ");
        wordLength = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    // prompt the user for number of guesses 

    System.out.println("How many guesses do you want to have? ");
    guessNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(guessNumber < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Number of guesses has to be a postive integer. ");
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired number of guesses: ");
        guessNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
    }




    }
```

}

**My goal is to prompt the user for a word length and if the desired word length does not exist in the dictionary.txt file then it keeps asking until a valid response is given.**

**I would also like to be able to prints how many words have a given word length (e.g if user types in "10", then it displays how many words in dictionary.txt have the length of 10 letters.**

The following part of the code is the one I hope to replace with code that reads the txt file and acts thereafter:

```
while(wordLength < 0 || wordLength > 26)
{
    System.out.println("This is not a valid word length. ");
    System.out.println("Please enter the desired word length: ");
    wordLength = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

It is possible that I have taken the wrong approach, so all feedback is very welcome!

Comment: How did you process the word which you read from file?

Comment: What does dictionary.txt look like? In generally, you need to read all words from dictionary.txt and create a map (word length to number of words with the corresponding length mapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can be used to establish a count of words of each word length.

```
// map where the key is the length of a word and
// the value is the number of words of that length
Map<Integer, Integer> numberOfWordsOfLength = new HashMap<>();

Scanner dictionaryScanner = new Scanner(file);

while (dictionaryScanner.hasNext())
{
   String word = dictionaryScanner.next();
   int wordLength = word.length();
   numberOfWordsOfLength.put(wordLength, 1 +
      numberOfWordsOfLength.containsKey(wordLength) ?
      numberOfWordsOfLength.get(wordLength) :
      0);
}
```

Then, when you want to know if there are any words of a given length, you can use this.

```
numberOfWordsOfLength.containsKey(length)
```

When you want to get the number of words in the dictionay that have a given length, you can use this.

```
numberOfWordsOfLength.get(length)
```

---

Later, when you want to select a random word of a given length, you can do something like this.

```
int wordIndex = new Random().nextInt(numberOfWordsOfLength.get(length));
Scanner dictionaryScanner = new Scanner(file);
String word;
while (dictionaryScanner.hasNext())
{
   String candidateWord = dictionaryScanner.next();
   if (candidateWord.length() != length) continue;
   if (wordIndex == 0)
   {
      word = candidateWord;
      break;
   }
   --wordIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag)
    {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(120000);
        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if(s.length() == wordLength)
            {
                words.add(s);
            }
        }
        if(words.isEmpty())
        {
            System.err.print("Invalid word length, please try again\n>");
            wordLength = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            System.out.println("There were " + words.size() + " such words");
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does it work?